# Generating file which can Excel easily open and save

Tags: excel, csv, xslt, format, export

i am exporting data from database to file, which can Excel read and save.

- (CSV) I generate csv, with default format (according to RFC 4180, comma delimeter). As expected, stupid excel read all data and place it to one cell.
- (CSV with semicolon delimeter), this one excel read fine, but after change some value and press save (CTRL+S), stupid excel saved it to unreadable file (well done!). No delimeters, no string separators. Ok, so i tried to save it as (CSV format with SEMICOLON delimeter), saved file looks ok, but after opening it with excel, error message was showed - INCORRECT FORMAT - no cell found :D really?!
- Generating .xsl file in php. It take too much RAM (about 2GB), so it cant be used.

Do you know any good format, which can excel easily open and easily save?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: CSV is the convenient format. Use the Semicolon so that Excel will open an put data in proper table format. Then you should be able to save it back to CSV at any time. Show us an example of your CSV semicolon output format maybe you have an issue in the data.

Comment: INPUT FORMAT:
"ID";"Kód";"Název";"Množství";"Cena";"Stará cena";

OUTPUT FORMAT:
ID;Kód;Název;Množství;Cena;Stará cena....................As you can see, excel forgot on string separators.

Comment: What "string separators"?

Comment: The first entry should not be "ID". See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/215591 ;-). Try `id;Kód;Název;Množství;Cena;Stará cena`. But best approach will be using really Excel file formats. If PHP can't create them, then avoid PHP.

Comment: generated input format is OK, thats readable for excel. But if i press CTRL+S, excel saved it to output format, which is not readable for excel.

Comment: Simply try with lowercase `id` in `A1`. It will work then.

Comment: Axel Richter: THANKS! thats work. Excel determine file format by extension (.csv), and then he change it to different format (SYLK maybe?), because he found "ID" on begining of file. Thats why, it wasnt readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is off-topic, but IMHO [Excel 2002/2003 XML Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpreadsheetML) would be the best choice in your circumstances.

The reason for this is that the data in this format is *typed* - so you will not see numbers misinterpreted as dates, or phone numbers with leading zeros stripped. I am not aware of the kind of problems you describe, so I cannot say for sure how those will be affected.